# SFTP BizTalk 2013 adapter error

Tags: biztalk, sftp, filezilla, biztalk-2013

I am trying to connect to filezilla SFTP server using SFTP BizTalk adapter but I am getting this error

```
The Messaging Engine failed to add a receive location "SFTPReceivePortReceiveLocation" with URL "sftp://127.0.0.1:990/.*" to the adapter "SFTP". Reason: "Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.SftpInvoker.SftpException: Open SFTP connection error.
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.SftpInvoker.SftpInvoker.Open()
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Sftp.SftpConnection.OpenUnderlyingConnection(SftpConnectionProperties connectionProperties)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapters.CommonHelpers.Connection`3.ConnectionPool`3.GetConnection(T1 connectionProperties, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapters.CommonHelpers.Connection`3.GetConnection(T connectionProperties, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Sftp.SftpRLConfig.ValidateConfiguration(SftpReceivePropertyBag receivePropertyBag)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Sftp.SftpRLConfig.CreateBinding(RHConfig rhConfig)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BtsServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnBeginOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfReceiveEndpoint.Enable()
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfReceiveEndpoint..ctor(BizTalkEndpointContext endpointContext, IBTTransportProxy transportProxy, ControlledTermination control)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfReceiver`2.AddReceiveEndpoint(String url, IPropertyBag adapterConfig, IPropertyBag bizTalkConfig)".
```

here is my sftp adapter configurations

[image: sftp adapter configuration]

and here is my sftp server configurations

[image: sftp server configurations]

and here how i generated private key

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are connecting to FTPS server with SFTP client. [FTPS and SFTP](https://www.eldos.com/security/articles/4672.php) are completely different protocols.

Comment: it is true eguene so can you tell me the best way to connect to sftp

Comment: @hazem if you try to connect to SFTP server, then your choice of the adapter is right, but you are trying to connect not to SFTP server!

Comment: thanks Eugene it is working now. it is my bad i should use ssh not ssl